# gnu parallel with no argument script

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have 4 cores, and 4 python script files `preprocess0.py`, `preprocess1.py`, `preprocess2.py`, `preprocess3.py`. I would like to run these 4 processes in parallel using GNU `parallel`. I do not have input files. The input file is hardcoded inside each `*.py` file (it's read only, so it's ok). I would like to output the results to a `file0.csv` ... `file3.csv` files. This is as far as I've come:

```
parallel -j4 --progress python preprocess*.py ::: '>' ./file{}.csv
```

But it just stays there without writing anything, as if waiting for some input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
parallel -j4 --progress 'python {} > ./file{}.csv' ::: preprocess*.py
```

That would create files called `filepreprocess1.py.csv`... You could use

```
parallel -j4 --progress 'python {} > ./file{#}.csv' ::: preprocess*.py
```

instead to use the job number instead and get some `file1.csv`... files. Or if you want to extract the number for the file names:

```
parallel -j4 --progress 'python {} > ./file{=s/[^\d]//g=}.csv' ::: preprocess*.py
```